# get exact value of parameter in array in doctrine manager

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine, fetch

```
$sql1 = "SELECT website_url FROM vendor_info WHERE $whereStr";
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $stmt = $em->getConnection()->prepare($sql1);
    $stmt->execute();
    $website_url = $stmt->fetchAll();

     foreach ($website_url as $vendorInfo) {
        dd($vendorInfo);
  
       $website = $this->url2png_v6($vendorInfo);
    }
```

I am using this query to fetch website url from data base
by using dd($vendorInfor); i can see the data is fetching.

[image]

I need to pas the only website url to the function.
`$this->url2png_v6($vendorInfo);`
how can I fetch the only url without its parameter name.

I am new in this technology.

Comment: $this->url2png_v6($vendorInfo[0]);

Comment: it returns the error with message "Undefined offset: 0"

Comment: Sorry, try $this->url2png_v6($vendorInfo["website_url"]);